# Laravel 5 ajax loop TokenMismatchException and cipher invalid

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.2 application, I'm trying to post some URLs via ajax in a loop but I get problems with both:

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

and

> TokenMismatchException

Javascript code:

```
urls.each(function(url) {
    var data = {
        urls: url.value
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/checkUrl",
        data: data,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{!! csrf_token() !!}'},

        success: function (data) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(result['msg']);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('Error: ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('APP_URI')], function() {

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

        Route::post('ajax/checkUrl', 'AjaxController@checkUrl');

    });

});
```

My AjaxController method is just following each URL with cURL, get some data and passing it back to the view.

Usually, I get the error

> production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in C:\wamp\www\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:45

It works first but after ~50 ajax requests, some of them starts to fail with 500 (Internal Server Error).

I have tried with:

- Excluded the ajax URL in VerifyCsrfToken Middleware.
- Modified VerifyCsrfToken Middleware as some people at Stackoverflow suggested
- Generated a new App key

In my config/app.php I have:

```
 'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

My code works fine standalone outside the Laravel application so I don't know why I get these errors, even if I exclude the URL from CSRF protection?

These errors occurs on localhost. The production server generates **401 Unauthorized** after ~100 ajax requests and sometimes logs me out.

Any suggestions why this occurs?

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan key:generate` command?

Comment: Yes I have, and the key is in my .env file!